# Encoding MySQL data to JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

Can anyone tell me why this is not working. I think I have literally looked at every video and webpage that talks about this and still all I get is a blank page and I have tried so many different ways. Here is my code. The screen is just blank when it's echoed. I am using PHP 5.6

```
    //header('Content-Type: application/json');
include_once('../db.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `id` ASC";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = ['id' => $row['id'], 'title'=> $row['title'], 'date' => $row['date'], 'header' => $row['header'], 'content'=> $row['content']];
}
//print_r($array);
echo json_encode($array);
//print_r($array);
echo count($array);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

If you want to see the results the site is http://bit.ly/1iAMnot

Here is what the print_r says. I'm only going to put one array because there are multiple.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => Explore More
    [title] => Explore More
    [2] => 2015-08-22 11:58:46
    [date] => 2015-08-22 11:58:46
    [3] => http://passionla.com/img/blog/explore-more.jpg
    [header] => http://passionla.com/img/blog/explore-more.jpg
    [4] => "For since the creation of the world God's invisible qualities--his eternal power and divine nature--have been clearly seen, being understood from what has been made, so that people are without excuse."
<br /><br />
- Romans 1:2
<br /><br />
The world around us is amazing. If you have recently seen a sunset or even just the wind blow through the leaves, causing them to rustle on the tree, you have witnessed just a piece of God's divine masterpiece that we can see in nature. 
<br /><br />
His beauty is all around you. Like the verse from romans says, His eternal power and divine nature are seen clearly in his creation. It is easy to get caught up in our busy lives and never look around.
<br /><br />
You don't have to go far to see god's magnificence. Take some time today to sit outside, to take a hike, or go for a walk with the intent of seeing God's majesty. Remember to take a second to look around and appreciate the glorious god that created you. 
<br /><br />
Explore more, He's created a big world out there.
    [content] => "For since the creation of the world God's invisible qualities--his eternal power and divine nature--have been clearly seen, being understood from what has been made, so that people are without excuse."
<br /><br />
- Romans 1:2
<br /><br />
The world around us is amazing. If you have recently seen a sunset or even just the wind blow through the leaves, causing them to rustle on the tree, you have witnessed just a piece of God's divine masterpiece that we can see in nature. 
<br /><br />
His beauty is all around you. Like the verse from romans says, His eternal power and divine nature are seen clearly in his creation. It is easy to get caught up in our busy lives and never look around.
<br /><br />
You don't have to go far to see god's magnificence. Take some time today to sit outside, to take a hike, or go for a walk with the intent of seeing God's majesty. Remember to take a second to look around and appreciate the glorious god that created you. 
<br /><br />
Explore more, He's created a big world out there.
)
```

Comment: When you do `print_r($row);`? Is there a result?

Comment: @aldrin27 yes it's prints all the arrays

Comment: Can i see the output?

Comment: @aldrin27 Yeah take a look at the link

Comment: Sorry it's block. Can you include that inside your question?

Comment: Try my answer if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Because my $row['content'] contained UTF-8 characters, I had to put utf8_encode($row['content']) and write out the array like this

```
$array[] = ['id' => $row['id'], 'title'=> $row['title'], 'date' => $row['date'], 'header' => $row['header'], 'content'=> utf8_encode($row['content'])];
```

Otherwise if I wrote

```
$array[] = utf8_encode($row)
```

I would give me an error. I hope this can help anyone else with this question.

Comment: I think add that inside your header too. To encode all results to utf8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = ['id' => $row['id'], 'title'=> $row['title'], 'date' => $row['date'], 'header' => $row['header'], 'content'=> $row['content']];
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: It's still just a blank page. I don't know if it could be with my server at DreamHost

Comment: Try to print_r($array);

Comment: That also prints the array just like this. I took out the data to save room
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [title] => 
            [date] => 
            [header] => 
            [content] => 
        )`

Comment: It's not storing on your variable. Hmm. try to remove your header?

Comment: It looks the exact same.

Comment: And to clarify the array is storing my id, title, etc. I just took it out to save space on the comments

Comment: It displays the 2 echo's?

Comment: I used the count just to make sure all the data was going through. The json_ecode doesn't display anything still not null or anything

Comment: I finally figured it out with your help too so thank you. I posted the answer